# Time/Date indicator doesn't appear in the panel

Tags: 11.04, clock, indicator

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty) and now the date/time does not show up in the app indicator area in the top panel.  I know that quite a few of the applets/indicators no longer work in Natty, but surely the date/time does as it's part of Ubuntu itself.  Any ideas on how to get this back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you have [indicator-datetime](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime) installed

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
```

then log out and back in.